# Git reset not making any changes to local or remote

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I've got a Bitbucket repo that needs to be `git reset --hard` to a specific commit. Prior to this operation, I had this:

```
% git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 16 and 15 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I ran the `git reset --hard` command locally with a commit ID like this:

`git reset --hard 798cd84`

Then I ran `git pull` and the expected fast-forward occurred.

```
Updating 798cd845..22bd077a
Fast-forward
.
.
.
24 files changed, 705 insertions(+), 80 deletions(-)
```

After that, I did `git status` and saw that it was saying

```
% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

but there was no change locally to `git log`. I tried `git commit -m "my comments"` and that resulted in nothing being committed, obviously.

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

On Bitbucket there was no change, again obviously, because I didn't have anything to push. But when I try to push anything, nothing goes to the remote. It just says `Everything up-to-date`.

So, how do I effect this change on the remote if there's nothing locally that I can do with `git commit` or `git push`?

If I've severely messed this up, how do I get back to good locally so I can try something else?

Comment: You're saying nothing was changed locally, but the output `24 files changed, 705 insertions(+), 80 deletions(-)` says otherwise

Comment: It's not clear what your actual goal is. Your question seems to be "how do I effect this change on the remote" but you didn't say what "this change" actually is. Also, why did you reset hard `master` to commit 798cd84 locally and then pull `origin/master` right after? Did you want to get rid of whatever you had on local master and set it the remote master? If yes you could have just reset hard to `origin/master` in the first place- but no worries- you just did it in two commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your confusion correctly, I think the key is this line:

> Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 16 and 15 different commits each, respectively.

So, there was a common history on both versions of the branch, and then:

- 16 commits in your local history
- 15 commits in the remote history

Given how similar the numbers are, it's fairly like that *15 of the 16 local commits* were *parallel versions* of the 15 remote commits. That is, either you or someone else has run `git rebase` or a related command, and created new versions of those commits.

So, when you discarded your 16 commits, and pulled in the remote 15 commits, *most of the log history will look the same* - all the same commit messages, authors, and authorship dates, except for that one extra commit which you've discarded.

In other words, it only looks like syncing up with the remote branch made no difference because *it was already very similar*.

Comment: Yes, prior to this I had attempted several rebases that failed and now I'm just trying to reset to a "known good" state. If I add a new file or other change for new code, will that likely start things in the right direction again?

Comment: @user3169905 Yes, all the outputs you've shown suggest that you've successfully made your local branch match the remote one.

Comment: Note that if you had carefully saved away all the *hash IDs*, you would have seen that they were all different. Different hash IDs, same (modulo one timestamp) content.